# Lambda how to get ThenInclude at the same time in dbcontext

Tags: c#, lambda

I have 4 classes in dbcontext,it's EventRemind.cs Event.cs House.cs Customer.cs,the code like this:

```
public class EventRemind
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerEventId { get; set; }

    public DateTime RemindTime { get; set; }

    public bool HasRead { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerEventId")]
    public virtual Event CustomerEvent { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int HouseId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(800)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HouseId")]
    public virtual House House { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EventRemind> EventReminds { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> HouseEvents { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> CustomerEvents { get; set; }
}
```

and my dbcontext is this:

```
public class DataContext:DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<EventRemind> EventReminds { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public DbSet<House> Houses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

that means an eventRemind include an event,an event include a house and a customer,now what puzzles me is that what should I do to get the House and Customer at the same time from EventReminds,what I want is this:

```
var query = _dataContext.EventReminds.Include(c => c.CustomerEvent)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Customer).ThenInclude(c => c.House //this get a compile error);
```

why dis this happen? Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try to reduce your code to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your last operator should be just `Include`. Try this:

```
var query = _dataContext.EventReminds
            .Include(c => c.CustomerEvent)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Customer)
            .Include(c => c.House);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code following way.

Way1

```
var query = 
_dataContext.EventReminds.Include(c => c.CustomerEvent).ThenInclude(c => c.Customer)
                         .Include(c=> c.CustomerEvent).ThenInclude(c => c.House);
```

Way2 (If property is not collection then it is usefull)

```
var query = 
_dataContext.EventReminds.Include(c=> c.CustomerEvent).
                     .Include(c=> c.CustomerEvent.Customer)
                     .Include(c=> c.CustomerEvent.House);
```